# Flutter local notification custom sound

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

In debug mode, when i send notification, the custom sound plays without any issue. However, in release mode, the default notification sound of the device plays. I am using flutter 3.7.8 and Android Gradle Plugin version 7.1.2.

Does flutter include the mp3 sound which is located in android/app/src/main/res/raw or do we have to specifically mention somewhere before compiling the appbundle

Thanks and regards